# Get latest created posts but in each page should not be more than 1 post per user

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I have a Post model.

```
class Post {
   id, 
   title,
   user_id
   ...
}
```

My goal is to get the latest created posts by pagination. But I don't want to get the same user's two posts on one page.

```
Post::onePostPerUser()->orderByDesc('id')->simplePaginate(5)
```

For example, when the page is 1, I want to get posts (100, 98, 96, 95, 94). In the next page (99, 97, .....

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 99 | 1 |
| 98 | 2 |
| 97 | 2 |
| 96 | 3 |
| 95 | 4 |
| 94 | 5 |
| 93 | 6 |

I have tried to write scope using the partition, but it's correct only for 1 page.

```
public function scopeOnePostPerUser($query)
{
    return $query->selectRaw('*')
        ->fromSub(function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn')
                ->from('posts');
        }, 'posts')
        ->where('rn', '=', 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any scope just user group by and latest methods.

```
$posts = Post::latest('id')->groupBy('user_id')->simplePaginate(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , but unfortunatelly it's  not working. I got posts ordered by id desc, but there were few posts in same page for same user.

Comment: let me go over trough it and reupdate the answer.

Comment: you want one post per user and this return more than one? just I am getting myself clear

Comment: actually you can use group by. you don't need to create a complex query. let me update the answer